# Pyspark - how to create a spark dataframe from xlsx bytes data stored in a variable?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm using requests to authenticate into a website and download an xlsx report. This website does not disponibilize any other format.

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.request(
    method = 'POST', 
    url = #website
    data = {
        'email': #my email
        'password': #my password
        }
 )

#do some stuff with s until I get the report url

file = s.get(file_url)
```

`file is a request object with the file data

```
>>> file.content

Out: b'PK\x03\x04\x1/... more bytes data'
```

If I had a file on disk, I could do

```
sparkSession.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
  .option("dataAddress", "'Sheet1'!")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load(#path to file in disk)
```

But I don't have permission to writing files in the file system so I can't write the file and then load it. Also, it would be an unnecessary write-read step.

If I have the data in the variable, surely I can do something like

```
sparkSession.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
  .option("dataAddress", "'Sheet1'!")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load_from_bytes(file.content) #this method doesn't exists. This is what I want.
```

Is there a way to do it? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just store data into file on DBFS, and read it:

```py
with open("/dbfs/tmp/my_file.xslx", "wb") as f:
  f.write(file.content)
sparkSession.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
  .option("dataAddress", "'Sheet1'!")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("/tmp/my_file.xslx")
.... work with data from file

# remove file
dbutils.fs.rm("/tmp/my_file.xslx")
```

otherwise other nodes won't be able to access this file that exists only in memory on the driver node.

P.S. If you're doing this on community edition, then you need to write to local disk first, and then copy to DBFS:

```py
with open("/tmp/my_file.xslx", "wb") as f:
  f.write(file.content)
dbutils.fs.cp("file:///tmp/my_file.xslx", "dbfs:/tmp/my_file.xslx")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works, but because of acess control, I can't always write to dbfs. So your solution works if I run the code as a job, but does not work when I just run the notebook (development testing).

This is a perfectly fine solution, just not ideal for my situation. I chose another work around.

Comment: what doesn't work? show the error. DBFS root doesn't have any permissions

Comment: I can write the file to the local file system, but it raises an error when I cal dbutil.fs.cp to move the file to dbfs.

`py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Constructor public com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtilsParallel(org.apache.spark.SparkContext) is not whitelisted.`

Comment: ah, cluster with Table ACLs... let me think about that

Answer (score 0):

Update.

I haven't yet found the perferct workaround for this problem. I believe Alex Ott's answer will work for most people. Our development cluster, however, has access control that prevents me from writing or reading from dbfs. I could still run his solution as a job on a separate cluster without access control, but I can't test it during development, so I chose not to use it.

What I'm doing is making a pandas dataframe and converting that to a spark dataframe.

```
%pip install xlrd
```

```
pandas_df = pd.read_excel(file.content)

from pyspark.sql import types

file_struct = types.StructType([
  #... Sruct Fields and all that good stuff
])

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df, file_struct)

#... do stuff with spark_df
```

It is not very elegant, but it works both as a job and during testing, so I decided to go with it and move on with my life.